# Multiple SVN users with the same login credentials on a Unix machine

Tags: svn, ubuntu, commit, shared, multiple-users

Here's our usecase for small projectets that rarely require attention from multiple developers at the same time:

- Projects are on a shared Ubuntu dev server
- Shared office account used to access the actual dev server
- Developers have their own SVN user credentials
- User A) checks out the project and does a few commits
- User B) works on the same project few days later, but his commits are pushed to the repository with the credentials of the first committer.

How could we easily swap who the "committer" is on our dev box? Something like svn ci file --user "foo" -m "fixed stuff"? Googling for the issue gives me multiple hits which aren't exactly about what I'm trying.

Maybe I'm misusing SVN if I thought this should be possible, since from most sources I find that I'd have to run relocate commands and edit configuration files, which is not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn commit --username foo`
should do

Comment: D'oh. Thanks! I'm quite sure I've tried it already, but guess I just thought so. The reason I was asking for help was because I was under the impression this did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the whole point of having user names in the first place is so you can distinguish between who is doing what.  If user B is allowed to do checkins as use A then what's the point of having two users in the first place?  So generally the right answer is "don't do that" as it really messes with auditing, the logs and traceability.

It would be better to identify why and for who the commit was being done in the log message and always have user B committing as themselves.

Comment: But having multiple logins to our development servers and live servers is not feasible for us. Patricks answer works in our use case.

Comment: You don't need to do that though.  Use a http server for SVN which lets you have http based accounts which are *not* system accounts.  I'm doing just this, in fact, for a server of my own.  By setting up SVN over http you can avoid having developers to have access to the file system at all.  [It wasn't clear from your question that this was your concern].

Comment: "Shared office account used to access the actual dev server"
"Developers have their own SVN user credentials"

Guess I should have said we've already using WebDav, but I thought that was clear enough. These small projects are on the Dev server due they get worked on so rarely that there is no need to waste time syncing them and their dev databases on each developers machine independently. Pats answer was enough for what we needed. Thanks for your effort still +1

Answer (score 0):

Simple make users on the Ubuntu machine and give every user it's own home folder where he can checkout with it its own credentials...and of course can commit as well. The working copy should be exclusive for one developer or better person.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pwauth to authenticate using Unix creds. Its a bit of setup work, but it works very well: http://matthewrupert.net/2011/02/16/subversion-authentication-using-unix-accounts/